# jQuery lightGallery escKey won't close if thumbs are open

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

First, let me thank the author for this excellent lightbox! I noted that escKey would not close the gallery whenever the thumbs are open. Is this the intended behavior? The relevant code is:

```
if (_this.s.escKey === true && e.keyCode === 27 && !_this.$outer.hasClass('lg-thumb-open')
```

and in my local copy I just removed the third test, and escKey now closes the gallery irrespective of the state of the thumbnails. Is this going to be a problem?

Comment: Hi @Branislav . Can you please describe more your question?

Comment: No need: the author fixed this in the next release! Thanks for the prompt feedback.